# no animation in Blender

Tags: animation

This is my first query on this site. I am very new to Blender. Just done with basics. I have purchased one blender character online. it is completely rigged. I have inserted the keyframes as desired but character is not animating. Neither in the timeline (by holding the cursor and move) nor by Alt + A.
Please suggest.

Comment: Hey Sandeep! I'm not sure what's wrong. In order to animate characters, you need keyframes and such. If none exist, the character will just stay still. Are you looking for guidance on animating, or?? I just am not quite sure what the issue is

Comment: could you add the blend file?

Comment: Did you set at least two sets of keyframes at two different time position in the timeline, with the armature selected and in pose mode?